# Does storybook-build have an onComplete method?

Tags: storybook

i have a requirement to run a build on storybook then deploy it to an azure server

i've had a read of the docs >
[standalone-options](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/standalone-options/)

...and it looks like it's possible to run a build from a node CLI but how will i know if a build was successful and moreover how can i then attempt an upload when it's finished... is there an onComplete callback or something, any ideas?